# How to remove unique option using sequelize

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize at nodejs. 
When I was making, I set the unique option in a column called 'invoice'.
But since I need to remove the unique option, I have to use migration.

```
queryInterface.removeConstraint('my_some_table', 'my_constraint');
```

I saw this command, and I think it is not correct method for me.
How can I remove 'unique option' using migration at sequelize?

```
invoice: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        unique: true,  <<-- I want to remove this. 
        allowNull: false,
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the [Sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/migrations/) documentation and allows you to change the meta data on a column:

```
queryInterface.changeColumn(
  'nameOfAnExistingTable',
  'nameOfAnExistingAttribute',
  {
    type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 0.0
  }
)
```